# Running php mysql query in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a website which contains products with different prices, recently I created a MySQL database to take pricing and naming information from. To be able to connect to this database and get the data I require I have to use PHP, however, all my files are .html and are unable to run PHP code.

I tried to create a .htaccess file but that didn't work, I could not even access the specific page I tried it on after that. The file was just saved to my computer for some reason .htaccess used:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Is there any other way to run PHP code in HTML?
Or do I have to change all of my 200 .html files to PHP?

And is it going to cause any problems with the website if all files are .php?

Thank you!

Comment: that rule allows PHP files ( with `.php` extension ) to be run using `.html` extension - so you would, in the browser, call `http://www.server.com/banana.html` but in actual fact are running the file `banana.php` etc so that rule will not help you

Comment: you could write a single php script that will scan your webserver, find all html/htm files and create a copy saved as `.php` ~ you could even add various `includes` using that same script

Comment: Okay, however lets say if the majority of the files are .php, will that cause any issues on the website? Or is PHP able to run the HTML code as .html would?

Comment: `Okay, however lets say if the majority of the files are .php, will that cause any issues on the website? Or is PHP able to run the HTML code as .html would?` ...I don't see any problem with that

Comment: https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/

Comment: Another option is to use a slightly different architecture, where you just add Javascript to the HTML files, and the JavaScript makes AJAX requests to PHP files, which execute their scripts separately, and return data back to the JavaScript, which then updates the page (without the user needing to refresh). That way you can keep the server-side functionality separate (like an API, more or less) from the user interface. Then you don't need to worry about whether your HTML files will be parsed by the PHP interpreter or not.